# SQL 2022 ssisdb always on support - patching requires AG recreation? And does auto failover detection still apply to SQL 2022?

Tags: sql-server, patching, sql-server-2022, cumulative-update

My setup is a 2 node AG.

SQL 2022 Enterprise.

SSISDB is part of the AG, and I have configured SSIS high availability (enabled SSIS Support for Always On) as per this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver16#Firsttime

During cumulative update installation I take out the ssis db from the AG and then patch the nodes (secondary first, failover, patch current secondary, failback). Post patching I add the ssis db backup into the AG, and enable the always on support for ssisdb by right clicking on the integration services catalog.

What is confusing me is the `Information about SSIS with always on` section on the cumulative updates page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate11#notes-for-this-update (see under `Hybrid environment deployment`)

This takes me to the following link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/ssis-with-alwayson/ba-p/388091

There are 2 concerns I have regarding this link:

1. `then recreate the availability group.` - Why does it say AG must be recreated?
2. The re encrypt the master key section, and automatic failover detection - this section I believe is applicable only for SQL 2019 which didn't have the support for ssis with always on.

Plese can someone familiar with SQL 2022, AG, and patching guide me on the above points.